# C# Creating a Grading Program

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement

So I am  trying to create a gradeing program where the user inputs a number between 1-100 on subjects; math, gym and classroom and the average number comes up that gives the student a grade between A-F.

I am stuck at looping, i dont know how to code so that if I type in an average of ex 80 points the grade B comes up. It comes up unreachble code detected.

```
  static string GradeMe(int average)
 {
         int grades1 = 90; (took away the const)
         int grades2 = 75;

       if (grades1 >= 90 && grades1 <= 100) 
           { 
              return "Grade A"; 
           } 

     (???->) else if (grades2 >= 75 && grades32 <= 89) {return "Grade B";}
    }

static int CalculateAverageGrades(int math, int gym, int classroom)
  {
        int sum = math + gym + classroom;
        return sum / 3;
    }
      static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("math: ");
        int math= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("gym: ");
        int gym = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("classroom: ");
        int classroom = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int medeltal = CalculateAverageGrades(math, gym, classroom); //hämtar calculate metoden

        Console.WriteLine("medel: " + medeltal);

        string grade = GradeMe(medeltal);
        Console.WriteLine(grade);
```

Comment: Since you set grades1 = 90, the else if block will never be reached.

Comment: You don't check the input (`avarage`) in your GradeMe() method, you check the consts you declare in it. These can't change and will always evaluate to true in the first if. Therefore the "Unreachable code detected" warning.

Comment: Alright I think I understand because the first statement is true it never goes to the next one.. but how do I make it work. sorry about the const, lets forget about them.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `else if` construction:

```
  //TODO: out the right thresholds 
  static string GradeMe(int average) {
    if (average >= 90)           // 90+ 
      return "Grade A";
    else if (average >= 80)      // [80..90)
      return "Grade B";
    else if (average >= 70)      // [70..80)
      return "Grade C";
    else if (average >= 50)      // [50..70) 
      return "Grade D";
    else                         // less than 50
      return "Grade E";       
  }
```

Ternary operator `? :` is a *shorter* but *less readable* alternative:

```
  static string GradeMe(int average) {
    return average >= 90 ? "Grade A"
         : average >= 80 ? "Grade B"
         : average >= 70 ? "Grade C"
         : average >= 50 ? "Grade D"
         : "Grade E";
  }
```

**Edit:** If you want repeating, a *loop* is the solution; I suggest extracting method `ReadGrade` as well:

```
   static int ReadGrade(string title) {
     while (true) {
       Console.WriteLine(title);

       int result = 0;

       if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result) &&
           result >= 0 &&
           result <= 100)
         return result;

       Console.WriteLine("Please, try again"); 
     }
   }

   static void Main(string[] args) {
     do {
       int medeltal = (ReadGrade("math: ") +
                       ReadGrade("gym: ") + 
                       ReadGrade("classroom: ")) / 3;

       Console.WriteLine(GradeMe(medeltal));

       Console.WriteLine("Next grade (Y/N)?");
     }
     while (string.Equals("Y", 
                           Console.ReadLine().Trim(), 
                           StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
   }
```

Comment: follow up question, if I want to give the user an option to either get a new grade or exit the program.

Comment: @Helpfulraven: add a *loop*: keep on doing until user enters `n`; see my edit

Answer (score 0):

In function `GradeMe()` you create `const int grades1 = 90;` and `const int grades2 = 75;` and then check condition `if (grades1 >= 90 && grades1 <= 100)`, which is always true, because `grades1 >= 90` is true and `grades1 <= 100` is true. So your else statement will never be reached.

You have to check average value in "if" =>

```
if (average >= 90 && average <= 100)
{
    return "Grade A";
}
else if (average >= 75 && average < 90)
{
    return "Grade B";
}
else
{
    return "Grade C";
}
```

and etc.

The most important thing is that all parts of function must return some value. You have to write 'else' for the last case

Comment: Ok i get that but if I take away the const then I get a warning at the function GradeMe, it says "not all code paths return a value"?

Comment: @Helpfulraven Yes, because then , not all code paths return a value. (E.g.: What if grades1 = 0 and grades2 = 0 ?)

Comment: Already I am getting to understand this, but now when I debug what ever the average point I get it always give me the grade A.

Comment: @Helpfulraven, change parameters of function 'CalculateAverageGrades' to
CalculateAverageGrades(tenta, dugga, projekt). You have not define math, gym and classroom in Main function.

Answer (score 0):

*first you do not defined `grade32` but a grade2

*second they (`grade1`, `grade2`, `grade32`, ...) are not the incoming values, that the caller method pass to the `GradeMe()` method, but the `average` so you should compare those value with your Literal values.

third, your first condition will trap item with score of 90 to 100, so not that you can't, but you do not need to mention it again in your second condition expression, and just say it's bigger than 75 ...

```
if(x>=90 && x<=100) return "A";
if(x>=75) return "B";
if(x>=50) return "C";
....
return "F";
```

since you do use `return`, you also do not need the `else`, since the method will return, and you can omit all `else`s.